# incorrect syntax near ':' in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server Management Studio to run a script on SQL Server 2008.
Following simple statement throws error "Incorrect syntax near ':'".

```
:setvar DatabaseName "USHR1.2"
```

Curious, what's going on here. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Weird, I don't see any syntax errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK.. it was simple. Enabling the "SQLCMD Mode" from the SSMS menu solved the error. Thanks everyone for your replies.

I guess, there are tons of such "Incorrect syntax near 'x'" errors reported on stackoverflow. Guess, those will go away with this fix.

Comment: In case anyone (like me) is wondering how to enable "SQLCMD Mode", it's located underneath the Query menu. ;)

Answer (score 5):

use TSQL....

```
DECLARE @databaseName VARCHAR(7)
SET @databaseName = 'USHR1.2'
```

Comment: why 7 and not 128 (max general identifier length) or ~ even 180 (256 char file limit - 60 chars for default pathing)?  I don't think I would have just picked 56 arbitrarily, but I dont recall the reason for choosing it.

Answer (score 3):

For how to enable "SQLCMD Mode", please go to the link:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2405/sql-server-management-studio-sqlcmd-mode-option/

Answer (score 1):

Or use ' instead of "

Answer (score 0):

The SQL being executed could be meant for an Oracle database. The colon(:) in an Oracle statement indicates a "bind variable".

Below is example Dapper query with a parameter. Notice the SQL has different syntax depending on if the database is SQL Server or Oracle.

SQL Server: `select * from Thing where Name = @Name`

Oracle:     `select * from Thing where Name = :Name`